# Just started using Visual Studio and VSCode. When adding a variable declared in a class with a user defined one it prints out offset value

Tags: c++

Now while playing around with code I found out that adding to a value in an object which was previously defined in a class returns to me some offset value. In visual it is usually such that the integer retains its proper value until it something is added to it, then it offsets to -858993460 and adds it to that (ex if I add 2 it is now -858993458). Vs code is a bit weirder since it just slaps it around quite randomly. I don't know what to do in spite of this. Is my code just wrong? Code blocks and other online compilers seem to work fine, yet I can't find out why these two much more sophisticated ones cant.

On visual studio changing the solution config from debug to release changes the offset from -858993460 to 7.

code in question:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Car {
    int velocity;

public:
    Car() {
        velocity = 0;
        cout << "Velocity set\n";
    };

    Car(int v) {
        velocity= v+velocity;  //offset happens once this is run
        cout << "Velocity added\n";
    };

        void getVelocity()
        {
            cout<<"The car has a velocity of "<< velocity << endl;

        };
   
        ~Car() {
            cout << "Destroyed\n";
        }
};



int main()
{
    Car c2;
    c2.getVelocity();
    int a;
    cout << "Increase velocity by ? :\n";
    cin >> a;
    Car c1(a);
    c1.getVelocity();

}
```

I genuenly dont know what to do cause im still new to coding and learning about classes. Any help is greatly apreciated

Comment: `velocity` is uninitialized in `v+velocity`. You might want to use just `v`.

Comment: You seem to have serious misconceptions about how classes and class instances work, go back to your textbook please.

Comment: _"Is my code just wrong?"_  Your code is just wrong.  The comments and other text seem to imply that you are trying to **change** a `Car`'s velocity, but your program creates two `Car`s, each with a velocity that does not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor `Car(int v)` uses the variable `velocity` without initializing.

Instead of the constructor, it looks like you should add a member function to add some value to the velocity and use that to modify `c2` instead of creating a new car `c1`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Car {
    int velocity;

public:
    Car() {
        velocity = 0;
        cout << "Velocity set\n";
    };

    void addVelocity(int v) {
        velocity= v+velocity;
        cout << "Velocity added\n";
    };

    void getVelocity()
    {
        cout<<"The car has a velocity of "<< velocity << endl;

    };

    ~Car() {
        cout << "Destroyed\n";
    }
};



int main()
{
    Car c2;
    c2.getVelocity();
    int a;
    cout << "Increase velocity by ? :\n";
    cin >> a;
    c2.addVelocity(a);
    c2.getVelocity();

}
```